# Testing an application using libusb without real hardware

Tags: testing, libusb

One part of an application I am writing uses libusb to communicate with a device and I am having a hard time testing my code. Is there a framework to create fake usb devices or another way to mock libusb in order to better automate testing, to be able to test on a CI, reproduce edge cases etc?

Answer (score 0):

**umockdev** provides tools to record the properties and behaviour of particular devices, and to run a program or test suite under a test bed with the previously recorded devices loaded.

[Homepage](https://launchpad.net/umockdev) , [source code and example](https://github.com/martinpitt/umockdev)